# Date method in JavaScript behaving differently when storing in another variable

Tags: javascript, date

```
let currentTime = new Date(); 
currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
console.log(currentTime);
```

// Output Mon Sep 10 2018 23:41:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
==> give the output as expected and give all the method of date to currentTime such as currentTime.toUTCString, currentTime.toDateString, currentTime.toGMTString(), etc

```
let currentTime = new Date();
let oneDayTime = currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`enter code here`
console.log(oneDayTime);
```

// Output 1536603159306
==> No method of date available to oneDayTime variable such as  oneDayTime.toUTCString, oneDayTime.toDateString, oneDayTime.toGMTString(), etc

When storing the result in oneDayTime variable there is no Date method available to it and returning in epoch time I guess instead of complete Date.

What is it behaving such I way I am not able to understand?

Comment: Because thats what [`setTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) returns.

Comment: 1536603159306  is a time stamp. to decode it do new Date(1536603159306) and whatever methods you want to apply. Please read docs before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have your `Date` instance in `currentTime` variable. When you call `setTime` on it it mutates `currentTime` and returns timestamp of updated date ([MDN docs on setTime method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime#Return_value)). It seems like you are expecting `setTime` to return `this` (i.e. `currentTime`) but it's simply not what `setTime` returns.

If your intention is to create another `Date` instance based on `currentTime` you can try this:

```
const a = new Date();
const b = new Date(a.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Ok I got it. second variable need to a date .